# Unusually large deserialisation time

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-1.5

I'm doing a mapPartitions on a rdd cached in memory followed by a reduce. Here is my code snippet

```
// myRdd is an rdd consisting of Tuple2[Int,Long] 
myRdd.mapPartitions(rangify).reduce( (x,y) => (x._1+y._1,x._2 ++ y._2)) 

//The rangify function- For each partition, it's adding the first element of the tuples & constructing ranges from the second element of the tuples

def rangify(l: Iterator[ Tuple2[Int,Long] ]) : Iterator[ Tuple2[Long, List [ ArrayBuffer[ Tuple2[Long,Long] ] ] ] ]= { 
  var sum=0L 
  val mylist=ArrayBuffer[ Tuple2[Long,Long] ]() 

  if(l.isEmpty) 
    return List( (0L,List [ ArrayBuffer[ Tuple2[Long,Long] ] ] ())).toIterator 

  var prev= -1000L 
  var begin= -1000L 

  for (x <- l){ 
    sum+=x._1 

    if(prev<0){ 
      prev=x._2 
      begin=x._2 
    } 

    else if(x._2==prev+1) 
      prev=x._2 

    else { 
      mylist+=((begin,prev)) 
      prev=x._2 
      begin=x._2 
    } 
  } 

  mylist+= ((begin,prev)) 

  List((sum, List(mylist) ) ).toIterator 
}
```

The rdd is cached in memory. I'm using 20 executors with 1 core for each executor. The cached rdd has 60 blocks. The problem is for every 2-3 runs of the job, there is a task which has an abnormally large deserialisation time. Screenshot attached

[image]

These are the metrics for task 4. Task 4 is the bottom row in the table
[image]

What could be the reason for this behaviour ?

PS - 1. I don't get this behaviour in all the cases. I did many runs of the same job & i get this behaviour in around 40% of the cases

Spark log for the run - http://pastebin.com/jnqTzPXS

Comment: Maybe, would be node where reduce is done?
All data shuffle to one node to do reduce phase.

Comment: This doesn't happen always. I get stragglers in around 40% jobs

Comment: Then.. i dont know what's going on..:S

Comment: can you please put the logs also

Comment: you can find the logs at - http://pastebin.com/jnqTzPXS